# how do i check the RAM on my Ubuntu sever?

Tags: linux

I'm using an old laptop that originally had 512MB of RAM and installed Ubuntu Server 12.04
I upgraded the old 512MB memory card to 1GB memory card, and now i just want to check how much RAM my "laptop Ubuntu Server" actually recognized...

If someone knows the Ubuntu Server command to checking RAM that is being recognized, please let me know...

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your question is off topic for Serverfault because it doesn't appear to relate to servers/networking or desktop infrastructure in a professional environment. It may be on topic for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but please [search](http://superuser.com/search) their site for similar questions that may already have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure why both of the below answers were down voted. Both of the are ways to accomplish what you asked. Regardless, I've +1'ed both of them.

Comment: @EEAA Someone might be downvoting answers to questions that they feel should be flagged+ignored (perception of rep farming I guess), but that's kinda malicious and not really how it's supposed to work. Threw in a +1 of my own.

Comment: @EEAA, throw in 2 for me too. The answers are fine.

Answer (score 4):

Would

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
```

work for you?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous command you can also use: `free`